# kivy - all events of a class reference last instance

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and having a bit of trouble creating a touch event for my widget. 
The idea is that I will have many (generated) square cells in a scatter layout, and each of those will have their own `on_touch_down` events. However, when I right-click one of the cells, the even always fires on the last cell created - in this case `x=99 y=99`. I must be misunderstanding something about how the even propagation works, and I'd appreciate any help.

cell class:

```
class cell(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1)
    g = NumericProperty(1)
    b = NumericProperty(1)
    color = ReferenceListProperty(r,g,b)
    def __init__(self, id_x, id_y, **kwargs):
        super(cell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id_x=id_x
        self.id_y=id_y

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.button=="right": 
            self.test()
            return True
        else:
             super(cell, self).on_touch_down

    def test(self):
        print"*****"
        print "x = " + str(self.id_x)
        print "y = " + str(self.id_y)
        print "size = " + str(self.size)
        print "pos = " + str(self.pos) 
        self.color = (0,0,1)
```

building the cells in the app class:

```
def build(self):
        b = base() #this is just an empty BoxLayout
        startx = 0
        starty = 0
        for x in range(100):
            tmpArr = []
            for y in range(100):
                cellRef = cell(id_x = x, id_y=y,size=(10,10),pos=(startx, starty))
                b.mainLayout.add_widget(cellRef)
                tmpArr.append(cellRef)
                startx += 11
            allCells.append(tmpArr)
            starty += 11
            startx = 0
        return b
```

kv file:

```
<base>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    mainLayout: layoutS

    ScatterPlaneLayout:
        id:layoutS
        do_collide_after_children:True
        auto_bring_to_front: False
        scale_min:.3
        scale_max:5.
        do_rotation: False

<cell>:
    size_hint:(None,None)
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: self.color
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size
            pos:self.pos
```

Comment: I think ``id_x`` and ``id_y`` are changed in some way after generating a cell object. Make these two members as NumericProperties. And put ``return`` before ``super(cell, self).on_touch_down...``.

Comment: @cmdLP while this is certainly a good idea, i don't think that is the problem, because it is the (only) last square that changes its color, and that is dependent only on `self.color` which is a property already

Comment: I solved it: I have to check that the touch collides with the widget: `self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)`, other wise it starts iterating trough all the widgets in reverse order, and `return True` makes it stop at the last one